# DjangoRestFramework: how to import csv file in django-restapi?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, rest, csv, django-rest-framework

recently i followed this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/packages/2016/08/11/django-import-export.html), but it was completely based on server side rendering. i didn't get my answer as expected what i am looking for. i want exactly same as with rest-api.

> if anyone could help
>   me what i am looking for then would be much appreciated. thank you in advance!

i just tried in this way but it giving me error that method is not allowed!

```
from .resources import PersonResource

class UploadAPIView(APIView):
    def simple_upload(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            person_resource = PersonResource()
            dataset = Dataset()
            new_persons = request.FILES['myfile']

            imported_data = dataset.load(new_persons.read())
            result = person_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)  # Test the data import

            if not result.has_errors():
                person_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)  # Actually import now
```